# How to write that special select query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, select

I have a post class :

```
class Post
{
public int ID;
public int? ParentID;
}
```

The only difference between answer and question in post class is that question has parend id equals null.

And I want to write one query which always return question and it's answers no matter i pass to it ID of question or ID of answer 
  for example:

I have ID=1 and don't know that it is ID of answer or question but if it is question ID i want to get that question and answers from post class

```
var selectquestionbyquestionid= from p in posts where p.ParentID==id || p.ID==id select p; 
(it's query only for first variant)
```

but if ID=1 is ID of answer and want to get question of that answer and all answers of that question

Is it possible ?

**Update (following Jon Skeet advice):**
  Class Post looks like that:

```
  class Post
    {
    public int ID;
    public int QuestionID;
    }
```

And if post is a question it has QuestionID equals it's own Id, but still i would like to write one query to do this, i know it is easier to write two

Comment: See my edit - I've moved the suggest single query to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: With the new QuestionID field instead, I suspect this will work:

```
var query = from post in posts
            where post.ID == id
            join related in posts on post.QuestionID equals related.QuestionID
            select related;
```

(You might want to try reversing the order of the join to see if that affects the query plan for the generated SQL.)

---

(The original question used a nullable ParentID field instead of QuestionID.)

Do you absolutely *have* to do it in one query? I'm sure it will be possible, but it's likely to be uglier than splitting it up:

```
var post = posts.Where(p => p.ID == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

if (post == null)
{
    // No such question - deal with it
}
int questonID = post.ParentID ?? post.ID;

var allPosts = posts.Where(p => p.ID == questionID || p.ParentID == questionID);
```

One thing to note: if you could change it from "ParentID" to "QuestionID" and make it non-nullable, such that a question had its *own* ID as the QuestionID, the queries would become a bit simpler.

---

If you *really* want to do this in one query, you *may* be able to do it as:

```
var query = from post in posts
            where post.ID == id
            let questionID = post.ParentID ?? post.ID
            from related in posts
            where related.ID == questionID || related.ParentID == questionID
            select related;
```

I don't know what LINQ to SQL will make of that though.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question, what about performance of these queries, optimally i would like to write one query to do that all but keep it as simple as possible, so when user browse question with question id I run only one query but when by mistake browse by answer id i want to get handle that too. (sorry for my inglish)

Comment: I wouldn't like to guess at the performance. With suitable indexes it should be pretty good though. Try it and see - and look at the query plan.